# biblioteca em Python para trabalhar com captura de video

Tags: python

Existe alguma biblioteca em Python que seja eficiente( até mais que a OpenCV) para trabalhar com captura de vídeo e no redimensionamento do tamanho dele ( alterar o tamanho do view da imagem sem alterar muito a qualidade ) ?

## EDITADO :

No meu caso eu quero capturar o vídeo e redimensiona-lo( dar zoom ) em tempo real( tipo aperta uma tecla e dá zoom de 2x na imagem capturada ). Por isso tem que ser uma biblioteca boa de captura de vídeo em tempo real pois pra zoons maiores  a imagem borra muito, ou seja, a biblioteca  teria que ter um " tratamento de imagens" quando captura a imagem ou quando a redimensiona.

Comment: Quanto ao dar zoom e a imagem borrar não depende das bibliotecas de captura de imagens mas sim da capacidade da sua câmera, pois uma câmera com baixa resolução não adianta vc ter uma boa lib se a imagem que ela vai tratar não tem qualidade.

Comment: Já sobre o tratamento de imagens por isso que eu citei "conhecimento concreto" ao usar essas libs isso exige conhecimento sobre colorozação,nitidez, gamma, correção de brilho contraste dentre outras técnicas, existem também filtros já presentes na própria lib, mas tudo isso eh relativo em relação a qualidade de captura da câmera.

Answer (score 3):

**OpenCV** é uma das lib mais antigas para Computer Vision, acredito que tenha outras lib poderosas na web mas é dificil competir com OpenCV pois a mesma foi criada pela própria intel, uma empresa de respeito no mercado atual, dependendo do que você quer fazer, se for só gravar um vídeo e redimensionar, existem saídas bem mais fáceis, pois para trabalhar com a mesma exige um conhecimento um pouco mais concreto em Computer Vision.
   
Pensando Nisso um Grupo de Programadores Criou uma Biblioteca Para Facilitar o trabalho com Computer Vision, batizaram-na de [SimpleCV](https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV) segue um exemplo de capturar um video da webcam, recorta-lo e um tamanho x utilizando **SimpleCV**

```
from SimpleCV import *    
cam = Camera()

while(True):
    cam.getImage().crop(200,200,200,200).show() # args is x,y, w,h
```

Comment: E só para esclarecer em RaspBerry funciona 100% também o código acima!

Comment: Pergunta editada